# How to get an Effect size for Negative Binomial Regression?

Tags: regression, effect-size, negative-binomial-distribution

Typically I use the confidence interval as an indicator of effect size for a negative binomial model, however, I have been told to provide an actual effect size (e.g., pseudo $R^2$). I have looked this up online and there is not much on the topic, and publications I have come across do not include it.

So my questions are, is there a way to get an effect size and if so how - and if not, why not?

Comment: You could ask them why they do not regard the coefficient with its confidence interval as an effect size although this would be dangerous if they are powerful people in your field.

Comment: I agree with @mdewey. The coefficient is an effect-size. Pseudo R^2 is clearly not and of debatable value (it does not reflect any specific effect). You could convert the coefficient and CI into percent change for a one unit change in the IV ((1-e^B)*100) or as the change in the counts.

Comment: I agree that the coefficients themselves are effect sizes (to be pedantic, the exponentiated coefficients, or incidence rate ratios, are more interpretable), and that $R^2$ on its own is not an effect size. In linear regression or ANOVA, Cohen's $\eta^2$ is a measure of effect size that's related to $R^2$, but I'm not aware that it's widely used, and I haven't seen it in count regressions.